# how to create and drop default constraint in oracle 11 g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

how to create and drop default constraint in oracle 11 g

Answer (score -1):

If by ***default constraint*** you are referring to a *column default value*, the below example should work for you.

In oracle, fields in a table have a *default value*.  Unless specified otherwise, the default value is `NULL`.  You can specify another value when creating a table, or afterward.

Here's an example, for movie characters.

First create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIE_CHARACTER(
  MOVIE_CHARACTER_NAME VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  MOVIE_CHARACTER_SPECIES_NAME VARCHAR2(128)
);
```

And insert data to see the default value:

```
INSERT INTO MOVIE_CHARACTER(MOVIE_CHARACTER_NAME) VALUES ('Ripley');
```

Then check the result:

```
SELECT * FROM MOVIE_CHARACTER;
```

Here we can see the default is `NULL` for our first record.

```
MOVIE_CHARACTER_NAME  MOVIE_CHARACTER_SPECIES_NAME  
Ripley
```

Then, set a default value for the species.  This is done with `ALTER TABLE`...`MODIFY` statement.  In this case, we will default the species of movie characters to *Wookie*

```
ALTER TABLE MOVIE_CHARACTER MODIFY(MOVIE_CHARACTER_SPECIES_NAME DEFAULT 'Wookie');

Table MOVIE_CHARACTER altered.
```

And insert additional data:

```
INSERT INTO MOVIE_CHARACTER(MOVIE_CHARACTER_NAME) VALUES ('Thor');
```

And check it:

```
SELECT * FROM MOVIE_CHARACTER;
```

Now new records are assigned *Wookie* species by default:

```
MOVIE_CHARACTER_NAME  MOVIE_CHARACTER_SPECIES_NAME  
Ripley                                              
Thor                  Wookie
```

Now we can remove the default value, by resetting it to `NULL`.  The syntax is the same as adding the default:

```
ALTER TABLE MOVIE_CHARACTER MODIFY(MOVIE_CHARACTER_SPECIES_NAME DEFAULT NULL);

Table MOVIE_CHARACTER altered.
```

And test it out after the change:

```
INSERT INTO MOVIE_CHARACTER(MOVIE_CHARACTER_NAME) VALUES ('Rocky');

SELECT * FROM MOVIE_CHARACTER;
```

Now the default is `NULL` again:

```
MOVIE_CHARACTER_NAME  MOVIE_CHARACTER_SPECIES_NAME  
Ripley                                              
Thor                  Wookie                        
Rocky
```

To override the default, you can provide the value:

```
INSERT INTO MOVIE_CHARACTER(MOVIE_CHARACTER_NAME, MOVIE_CHARACTER_SPECIES_NAME) VALUES ('Deckard','Android');
```

Then check the data:

```
SELECT * FROM MOVIE_CHARACTER;
```

The default is overriden:

```
MOVIE_CHARACTER_NAME  MOVIE_CHARACTER_SPECIES_NAME  
Ripley                                              
Thor                  Wookie                        
Rocky                                               
Deckard               Android
```

If you want to specify the default when creating a table, you can do so in this way.  In this example, `SEPERHERO`s have the *power* of *Flying* by default.

```
CREATE TABLE SUPERHERO(
  SUPERHERO_NAME VARCHAR2(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  SUPERHERO_POWER VARCHAR2(128) DEFAULT 'Flying'
);
```